# Getting matched fasta file

Tags: awk, bioinformatics

`list.txt`:

```
58759__len__2903
58759__len__2903
673957__len__1655
673957__len__1655
3566454__len__1744
```

`seq.fasta`:

```
>58759__len__2903
TTTTCCGTAGAGGAGATCCCTATTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGAGATCATTTT
>67777__len__2978
TTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
>673957__len__1655
CCCTATTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
>3566454__len__1744
GGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAGGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
```

`output.fasta`:

```
>58759__len__2903
TTTTCCGTAGAGGAGATCCCTATTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGAGATCATTTT
>673957__len__1655
CCCTATTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
>3566454__len__1744
GGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAGGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
```

Match line from `list.txt` (if duplicate line, use only unique line) to `seq.fasta` and extract the FASTA file as shown in output file.

Comment: Please include at least your current code. USE is not a programming service.

Comment: This is not duplicate question. My question is different in the aspect of sequence extraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple case you show is trivial. Your sequences are never more than a single line so you can simply use `grep` to search for each of your IDs and the line after them:

```
grep -Fwf list.txt -A 1  seq.fasta | grep -v '^--$'  > out.fasta
```

The `grep -v '^--$'` simply filters out the lines with `--` that `grep` adds between groups of output lines when using the `-A` option.

To also avoid the dupes, you can pass your list through (GNU) sort:

```
grep -Fwf <(sort -u list.txt) -A 1  seq.fasta | grep -v '^--$'  > out.fasta
```

The flags used are:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
          Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the  -o  or  --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

---

However, in most cases, your sequences will be several lines and that will not be enough. If you will be doing this kind of thing often, I suggest you install the `exonerate` suite of tools. They are generally extremely useful for bioinformatics work and include a nice tool called `fastafetch` that is designed to do exactly what you want:

1. Install the exonerate suite. This is in the repositories of Debian based systems, and is also available from [here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/%7Eguy/exonerate/).

   ```
    sudo apt-get install exonerate
   ```
2. Create an index for your fasta file. This is used for the rapid retrieval of sequences.

   ```
    fastaindex seq.fasta seq.idx
   ```
3. Extract your sequences:

   ```
    $ fastafetch -f seq.fasta -i seq.idx -Fq <(sort -u list.txt )
    >3566454__len__1744
    GGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAGGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
    >58759__len__2903
    TTTTCCGTAGAGGAGATCCCTATTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGAGATCATTTT
    >673957__len__1655
    CCCTATTTTTAGGTTTGTAAGGTTTGTAAGACCGTAGAG
   ```